# rpm package from python source

Tags: python, package, rpm, packaging, setup.py

I have a python script `MyScript.py`. I run it using `python MyScript.py [options]`. But I want to make rpm package from it. So I created `setup.py` and created rpm package by using `python setup.py bdist_rpm`. For this I changed file structure as below:

```
- MyScript
   - __init__.py
- setup.py
```

**setup.py:**

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup(name='MyScript',
      version='0.0.1',
      author='ABC XYZ',
      author_email='abc@xyz.com',
      packages=['MyScript']
      )
```

When I run `python setup.py bdist_rpm`, I get 2 rpm files (`noarch.rpm`, `src.rpm`) and 1 tar.gz file under dist folder which is created automatically. But When I use `rpm -i` on `norach.rpm` file, it just says that package is installed but I can not use the package when I try to run `MyScript` command in bash. Am I doing something wrong here? Please guide me if so. I am bit beginner to packaging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are doing something wrong :)

The fact that you created an rpm and provided a `MyScript` package does not mean that installing the rpm will expose an executable for you to run (i.e `$ MyScript ...`. To also making an executable available which will interact with the package, you need to provide an `entry_point` in your setup.py file.

An entry point pretty much maps a script which will be installed in the path to a function in your code and runs it.

Add something like this:

```
setup(name='MyScript',
      version='0.0.1',
      author='ABC XYZ',
      author_email='abc@xyz.com',
      packages=['MyScript'],
      entry_point={
          'console_scripts': [ 
              'MyScript = MyScript.__init__:FUNC_NAME'
          ]
      } 
  )
```

where `FUNC_NAME` is the name of the function in the `MyScript` package in the `__init__` module to invoke.

The general format (for future reference) of a console_script is:

```
'name_of_executable = package.module:function_to_execute'
```

An example can be found here: https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/